# How to handle FragmentTransaction (cached) hidden fragments during screen rotation?

Tags: java, android, performance, android-fragments, fragment

In my main layout I have a central container which contains a fragment.

I started with FragmentTransaction.replace(...) to replace the fragment with other fragments but this recreate each fragment on each replacement, which makes the UI laggy (some fragments have complexe layout etc).

Instead of replace(), some suggest using .show() and .hide() to "cache" rendered fragments, and which leads to the code below:

```
private HashMap<String, Fragment> mCachedFragments = new HashMap<String, Fragment>();
private Fragment mCurrentFragment = null;
@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    if (position == mCurrentSectionID)
        return;

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);

    if (mCurrentFragment != null) {
        Log.d("TRANSACTION", "putting fragment "+mCurrentFragment.getClass().getName());
        mCachedFragments.put(mCurrentFragment.getClass().getName(), mCurrentFragment);
        transaction.hide(mCurrentFragment);
    }
    Log.d("Nav", "selected: " + position);

    Fragment dest = null;
    switch (position) {
        case BitsListFragment.FRAGMENT_ID:
            dest = mCachedFragments.get(BitsListFragment.class.getName());
            if (dest == null) {
                dest = BitsListFragment.newInstance();
                transaction
                        .add(R.id.container, dest);
            } else {
                Log.d("TRANSACTION", "bitlist retrieved");
                transaction.show(dest);
            }
            onSectionAttached(BitsListFragment.FRAGMENT_ID);
            break;
        case AchievementsFragment.FRAGMENT_ID:
            dest = mCachedFragments.get(AchievementsFragment.class.getName());
            if (dest == null) {
                dest = AchievementsFragment.newInstance();
                transaction
                        .add(R.id.container, dest);
            } else {
                Log.d("TRANSACTION", "achievements retrieved");
                transaction.show(dest);
            }
            onSectionAttached(AchievementsFragment.FRAGMENT_ID);
            break;
        case StatsFragment.FRAGMENT_ID:
            dest = mCachedFragments.get(StatsFragment.class.getName());
            if (dest == null) {
                dest = StatsFragment.newInstance();
                transaction
                        .add(R.id.container, dest);
            } else {
                Log.d("TRANSACTION", "stats retrieved");
                transaction.show(dest);
            }
            onSectionAttached(StatsFragment.FRAGMENT_ID);
            break;
    }

    mCurrentFragment = dest;
    transaction.commit();
}
```

The code here works perfectly as long as the Activity does not gets recreated. The fragments gets retrieved and shown, and currentFragment is hidden when transition takes place.

As you can see, I'm basically keeping a reference to the CurrentFragment and a hashmap of all the cached fragments. The problem is that when I rotation the screen, the MainActivity gets recreated and these references are reset to null or emptied. Which ends up with BitsListFragment getting created multiple times and shown on screen overlapped.

**Is there a better way to cache fragments/replace fragments without recreating them?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually found another way to do this: instead of keeping an reference on my own, we can add the fragment to the backstack and then retrieve it using corresponding tag. This let's fragmentManager manages the caching by itself. And the second time you access a fragment, it doesn't gets recreated.

The only hack that you should watch out is to override onBackPressed() so that you don't return to last fragment if you don't need to.

```
@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    if (position == mCurrentSectionID)
        return;

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);

    Fragment dest;
    switch (position) {
        case BitsListFragment.FRAGMENT_ID:
            dest = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(BitsListFragment.class.getName());
            if (dest == null) {
                Log.d("TRANSACTION", "instanciating new fragment");
                dest = BitsListFragment.newInstance();
            }
            transaction.replace(R.id.container, dest, BitsListFragment.class.getName());
            transaction.addToBackStack(BitsListFragment.class.getName());
            break;
        case AchievementsFragment.FRAGMENT_ID:
            dest = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(AchievementsFragment.class.getName());
            if (dest == null) {
                Log.d("TRANSACTION", "instanciating new fragment");
                dest = AchievementsFragment.newInstance();
            }
            transaction.replace(R.id.container, dest, AchievementsFragment.class.getName());
            transaction.addToBackStack(AchievementsFragment.class.getName());
            break;
        case StatsFragment.FRAGMENT_ID:
            dest = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(StatsFragment.class.getName());
            if (dest == null) {
                Log.d("TRANSACTION", "instanciating new fragment");
                dest = StatsFragment.newInstance();
            }
            transaction.replace(R.id.container, dest, StatsFragment.class.getName());
            transaction.addToBackStack(StatsFragment.class.getName());
            break;
    }

    transaction.commit();
    onSectionAttached(position);
}
```